# C# Entity Framework, deleting child items then parent, The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Trying to delete child items first, then the parent. I am inside the same using statement.

Originally I had one call to `context.SaveChanges();` but I have changed to commit the child delete first, then try and delete the parent records, but I am still sometimes receiving this error message:

> The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint “FK_AccountQuestionMappings_AccountQuestions”. The conflict occurred in database “db”, table “dbo.AccountQuestionMappings”, column ‘QuestionId’. The statement has been terminated.

So the relationship is the questions in table `AccountQuestions` are the parent, and these are mapped and stored in the `AccountQuestionMappings` table. I am trying to delete them from the `AccountQuestionMappings` table, then from the `AccountQuestions` table.

```
using (var db = dataContext())
{
    if(questionInfo != null)
    {
        var questionIds = db.AccountQuestions.Where(q => q.AccountQuestionInfoId == questionInfo.Id).Select(s => s.Id).ToList();

        foreach (var question in questionIds)
        {
            var questionMapping = db.AccountQuestionMappings.Where(q => q.QuestionId == question).FirstOrDefault();

            if (questionMapping != null)
            {
                db.AccountQuestionMappings.Remove(questionMapping);
            }
        }

        db.SaveChanges();

        db.AccountQuestions.RemoveRange(db.AccountQuestions.Where(s => s.AccountQuestionInfoId == questionInfo.Id));
        db.SaveChanges(); // error occurs on this line saying due to there still being a child in the mappings table
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `FirstOrDefault()` to delete `AccountQuestionMappings`. So if there are multiple `AccountQuestionMappings` associated with `AccountQuestions` then it will only delete `first` one. So when you delete `AccountQuestions` it will throw error.

You can try updating code like below. Remove `FirstOrDefault()`. Update condition inside `if` statement. And use `RemoveRange`.

```
foreach (var question in questionIds)
{
    var questionMapping = db.AccountQuestionMappings.Where(q => q.QuestionId == question);

    if (questionMapping.Count() > 0)
    {
        db.AccountQuestionMappings.RemoveRange(questionMapping);
    }
}
```